# Create EF Core Include().ThenInclude() like function?

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm writing a few simple extension methods to create DTOs out of entities defined in the domain, however, those entities have properties that are also entities, and I'd like to be able to write something (that I personally find elegant) like they do in EF Core with Include().ThenInclude().

Ideally I'd like to be able to write something like

```cs
return myEntity.ToDto().Include(entity => entity.SubEntity).ThenInclude(subEntity => subEntity.AnotherSubEntity);
```

Is it possible?

The idea is that if I just call `ToDto()` I would simply receive a basic DTO object where all simple type properties are set but all complex type properties are `null`, unless I specify that I want to inclue one (or more) of the properties too.

Comment: A convenient way would be to use AutoMapper (ProjectTo) for this kind of requirement.

Comment: You can take a look at ORM patterns, which are about loading related data [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data)

Answer (score 0):

AutoMapper [Queryable Extensions](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Queryable-Extensions.html) provides a convenient way to query entities with relationships and map them to DTOs in one step. 
It produces an optimized SQL query needed to copy that data.

Example:

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
   cfg.CreateMap<BlogDTO, Blog>().ReverseMap();
   cfg.CreateMap<PostDTO, Post>().ReverseMap(); 
});


return _context.Blogs.Where(b => b.Id == Id)
        .Include(x => x.Posts)
        .ProjectTo<BlogDTO>(config)
        .ToList();
```

Comment: There is no need for `Include`.

Comment: Wouldn't that mean that I need to implement it within the repository? Or that my repository needs to return an IQueryable? In both cases my repository doesn't return domain objects anymore...?

Answer (score 0):

I've actually managed to do it by sort of copying how EF Core does it with a lot of reflection and expression trees, and by creating my own visitor to then process the whole expression tree.

I am now able to write code like: `myEntity.AsDtoable().Include( x => x.ComplexTypeProp ).ThenInclude( x => x.AnotherComplexTypeProp ).ToDto< EntityDto >();`

Comment: Can you share the code how you done it please

Comment: Hi @NahroFuad, I could but not here, it would be too long... There are quite a few classes involved.